# Can I access a secondary hard drive on another computer via AFP

Tags: macos, finder, afp

I am on machine LOC. I would like to connect to a directory on the second hard drive of machine REM. Both machines are running Lion 10.7.1. I use Finder on LOC and Command-K to connect to a server. I type in afp://192.168.1.3 (IP Address of REM) and authenticate as a user on REM with Admin priveleges. I am presented with an option to connect to any of several different folders, all of which reside on REM's primary (boot) hard drive. I would like to connect to a folder which resides on a second internal drive in REM, but I am not given this option. The folder on the second hard drive is owned by the Admin user I am connect to REM as, and has 755 permissions. I have created a symlink on REM under the home directory of the user I authenticate as. When I am logged in to REM locally as that same user, clicking on the symlink takes me to the folder on the secondary drive.

How can I access this folder via AFP from another computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Set up sharing on REM to share the root directory of the second drive.

You can right click and do it from the Finder or go in and manage all shares from the sharing system preference.

Comment: I was not able to find the context (right click) menu item to do this. I was able to use the sharing preference pane which worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ask for the information (CMD-I) of the secondary drive, and set the "shared" box. Then afp  is able to mount the secondary disk. Some difficulty may arise from "symbolic links" between drive (the links you create with unix command  ln -s ), and I had to use "hard link" ("create alias" from Finder menu, and probably Unix command "ln ", without option "-s").
Note that I have done all this not on the REM itself, by through the  "screen sharing" button that appears in the Finder window of the remote disk !  Fine application that avoided me to run between the two computers !